# Select the the last transaction of an item in a month

Tags: php, mysql

Im developing an inventory system. Here are my tables:

medicine Table:

```
medID| medDescription | medBeginningQty |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1    | Amplodipine    |5000             |
2    | Losartan 5mg   |5000             |
3    | Amoxicillin    |5000             |
4    | Paracetamol    |5000             |
5    | Ascorbic Acid  |5000             |
6    | Co-amoxiclav   |5000             |
7    | Alcohol        |5000             |
8    | Losartan 10mg  |5000             |
```

medicinetransac Table:

```
medTransacID|medID|transacType|transacQuantity|transacDate|transacCurrentBal 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1           |  1  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
2           |  2  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
3           |  3  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
4           |  4  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
5           |  5  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
6           |  6  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
7           |  7  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
8           |  8  | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01| 5000
9           |  1  | issuance  | 100           | 2019-07-01| 4900
10          |  2  | issuance  | 100           | 2019-07-01| 4900
11          |  3  | issuance  | 100           | 2019-07-01| 4900
12          |  1  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-07-15| 4700
13          |  2  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-07-15| 4700
14          |  3  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-07-15| 4700
15          |  2  | issuance  | 100           | 2019-08-02| 4600
16          |  5  | issuance  | 100           | 2019-08-02| 4900
17          |  3  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-08-10| 4500
18          |  5  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-08-10| 4800
19          |  6  | issuance  | 200           | 2019-08-10| 4800
```

I want to generate a monthly report where in i can get the last transaction of an item in that month, and also the last transaction of that item before that month to be used as its beginning balance of the given month.

Also, if there are no transactions in the given month, but the quantity is still greater than zero then might as well display it too. Here is my sample code that isn't working `Select * from medicine m left join medicinetransac mt on m.medID = mt.medID where month(mt.transacDate) = '$month'`.

This is the output i was hoping where `$month = "08"`:

```
medTransacID|medID|medDescription|transacType|BeginningBalanc|transacDate(beginning)|transacDate(last)|transacQuantity
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1           |  1  |Amplodipine   | issuance  | 4700          | 2019-07-15           | ----------      | -     
1           |  2  |Losartan 5mg  | issuance  | 4900          | 2019-07-15           | 2019-08-02      | 100   
1           |  3  |Amoxicillin   | issuance  | 4700          | 2019-07-15           | 2019-08-10      | 200   
1           |  4  |Paracetamol   | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01           | ----------    | -  
1           |  5  |Ascorbic Acid | issuance  | 5000          | 2018-10-01           | 2019-08-10      | 200  
1           |  6  |Co-Amoxiclav  | issuance  | 5000          | 2018-10-01           | 2019-08-10      | 200  
1           |  7  |Alcohol       | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01           | -               | -  
1           |  8  |Losartan 10mg | NewItem   | 5000          | 2018-10-01           | -               | -
```

Items with `medID = 4, 7, 8`are captured even though they don't have transactions in the given month because there quantity are still > 0.

Thank you! I hope you can understand how I write my question! by the way, im using PHP, im not hoping that everything will be done through query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there looks to be some ineffective ways you are going about your table structure, I'll try to address your concern, ignoring that.

So assuming you have PHP variables that contain:

```
$target_month = '08';
$target_year = date("Y");
```

We want to collect the year because we dont want sql to assume Aug 2019 is same as Aug 2018 and mix them.

Adjusting to your current structure, I'd first start of by getting a subquery of the last transactions this month for each item. We do this using a GROUP BY statement with a combo of MAX() aggregate function.

```
SELECT medID, MAX(medTransacID) AS lastTransacID
FROM medicinetransac 
WHERE MONTH(transacDate) = {$target_month} AND YEAR(transacDate) = {$target_year}
GROUP BY medId
```

Notice that we are not getting the last date (because we can have multiple transactions per date) so we get the highest transaction ID instead. Just make sure it is auto-incremented.

Now, to grab the previous month's data, there are a few assumptions. Do we need the *last* month's data or the last transaction before this month? There's a huge difference because what if we dont have transactions for the last month? What if the last time an item was purchased was 5 months ago? Do we use that? Or do we show blank? For this example, I'm going to assume you want the last transaction *before* this month, regardless if it was last month or 3 months ago.

```
SELECT medId, transacDate, transacCurrentBal
FROM medicinetransac a
WHERE medTransacID = (
    SELECT MAX(medTransacID) FROM medicinetransac b
    WHERE MONTH(transacDate) < {$target_month}
      AND YEAR(transacDate) <= {$target_year}
      AND b.medId = a.medId
      LIMIT 1
)
```

So in that query we pull the greatest transaction id found in any date before this month. Notice how I am using  < and <= for the dates.

We can now build this big query like so:

```
SELECT 
        med.medID,
        med.medDescription,
        tmd.transacType,
        topmt.transacCurrentBal AS beginningBalance,
        topmt.transacDate AS begginingBalanceDate,
        tmd.transacDate AS lastTransactionDate,
        tmd.transacQuantity AS lastTransactionQuantity
FROM medicine med

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT medID, MAX(medTransacID) AS lastTransacID
    FROM medicinetransac 
    WHERE MONTH(transacDate) = {$target_month} AND YEAR(transacDate) = {$target_year}
    GROUP BY medId
) table_of_last_transaction_ids tolti ON med.medID = tolti.medID

LEFT JOIN medicinetransac target_month_data tmd ON tmd.medTransacID = tolti.medTransacId

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT medId, transacDate, transacCurrentBal
    FROM medicinetransac a
    WHERE medTransacID = (
        SELECT MAX(medTransacID) FROM medicinetransac b
        WHERE MONTH(transacDate) < {$target_month}
          AND YEAR(transacDate) <= {$target_year}
          AND b.medId = a.medId
        LIMIT 1
    )
) table_of_previous_months_transaction topmt ON topmt.medId = med.medId
```

There's a few caveats for this however. Subqueries are generally slow and if you're using a more up to date version of mysql, I suggest you look into *window functions*. If the last subquery doesnt work, look into using a left join instead of a nested select. Im doing that just to show you the difference.

Also, a few tips;

1. try to avoid using nonalphanum characters as your column names and alias
2. make tables and columns more descriptive
3. stick to underscore_notation when working with databases (cleaner)
4. avoid redundancy in tables. notice how redundant transacType is? Why not use two separate tables for in/out transactions?

Hopefully this will help you out. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for you're answer sir! I will give it a try sir! Thank you!

Comment: when you said this line "I'm going to assume you want the last transaction before this month, regardless if it was last month or 3 months ago." - yes sir, correct, i just want to ask if this does cater if the last transaction was a year ago?

Comment: @GregNinobla yes it should still pull up the last transaction before this month regardless of when the last transaction was. But again, test it yourself and have a go. Also, if you think my post has answered your question, please dont forget to mark it as the correct answer. :)

Comment: i've just tried this and it works! i just have few, very few adjustments. But still, it really worked for me! thank you!

Comment: i have a bit of a problem, how about if the last transaction was last year, (it should still be displayed)? this line  "WHERE MONTH(transacDate) < {$target_month} AND YEAR(transacDate) <= {$target_year}", i think it only captures all previous months of the previous year.. for example if $year = 2019, and $month = 05, this line only captures all transactions 01, 02, 03, 04 month of the current year and previous year. it doesn't capture 6 to 12 months... am i correct?

Comment: @GregNinobla you're right. Another work-around is to just use a forced date as the limit. So something like WHERE transacDate < '{$target_year}-{$target_month}-01'       which assumes your db follows YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: that's exactly what i also think, but didn't try yet. More thanks to you sir!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some problem with your table structure. Because when I replicated the table on my pc. The query ran well without any error. BTW The answer to @Don Bhrayan Singh is quite good.